# How do I add a cookie to a urllib2 opener?

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2, cookielib

I have created an opener with `urllib2.build_opener()` that contains a `cookielib.CookieJar()`, and now I wish to manually add a cookie to the opener.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Like the second example of the `cookielib` documentation suggests:

```
import os, cookielib, urllib2
cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar()
cj.load(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".netscape", "cookies.txt"))
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
r = opener.open("http://example.com/")
```

Here's the link:

[Cookies examples](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#examples)

Above example applies to Mozilla cookies, but generic algorithm is the same.

If adding by hand is required, reading the documentation further, you can use:

http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html#module-Cookie `Cookie` object, which you fill up the way you see fit and further on add it to a `CookieJar` with

> **CookieJar.set_cookie(cookie)**
>
> Set a Cookie, without checking with policy to see whether or not it should be set.

Comment: Loading from a file isn't an option, I want to manually add the cookie using parameters (name, value, expiry).

Comment: says missing domain with SimpleCookie